# Using Fuse-Low Level API

Tags: c, filesystems, fuse

I am trying to implement a basic file system using Fuse Low level API. for basic read/write/mknod operations.
Will be grateful if any one can point to some examples, there is no documentation on fuse low level api.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Fuse actually ships with a few examples using the low-level API. Have a look at hello_ll.c.

https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/master/example/hello_ll.c

Comment: For anyone reading this, you may find it under a moved  URL: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/libfuse/libfuse/master/example/hello_ll.c

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunate the low level header, [`fuse_lowlevel.h`](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/master/include/fuse_lowlevel.h) and the library [source](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse) itself are the best reference on the low-level API. The higher level one is much nicer to use, I'd recommend that instead.